# I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't seem to download anything

Tags: software-installation, software-center, downloads

Let me just start with saying that I am very new to Linux in general. I recently installed 14.04 and I downloaded a couple of things first: Gimp and Chrome, but when I tried to get Steam it downloads but when I launch it, the terminal says:

> Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Then the terminal closes and a box comes up saying:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
>   libc.so.6

When I try to run "sudo apt-get -f install" it does this:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Correcting dependencies... Done
>   The following extra packages will be installed:
>     libc-bin
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:
>     libc-bin
>   0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 0 B/1,168 kB of archives.
>   After this operation, 3,529 kB of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>   Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
>   Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
>   dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
>   dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
>   Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

And then the software center says there is a problem with my current software. Can someone help?

Comment: You have 77 not upgraded packages. Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, then install it again.

Comment: Goes through some stuff then `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: libc-bin (>= 2.13)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
`

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo echo $PATH` please.

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
`

Comment: Please post the output of `which ldconfig`.

Comment: `which ldconfig` came up with nothing, just another command prompt. `ldconfig` came up with `The program 'ldconfig' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install libc-bin
`

Comment: Try my answer, if it does not work, comment again and we can figure it out in the chat.

Comment: It still comes up with nothing

Comment: Does the `sudo apt-get install libc-bin` inside the `chroot` work?

Comment: What is chroot and how do I get to it?

Comment: Just follow the steps in my answer below.

Comment: If you have troubles with any step let me know and I can explain further id needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but here's the answer. You need to install that library that Steam needs. Do so by running `sudo apt-get install libc6*`. This should fix the Steam problem and will hopefully solve the other one as well.

Comment: That comes up with 'E: Unmet dependencies. Try `apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: OK. Try installing `libc-bin`.

Comment: Part of response: Note:  `root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`

Comment: OK. Go to `/etc` and open `environment`. Make sure that it contains /usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin`.

Comment: All of those are present.

Comment: From a short look-up it looks like the `$PATH` error is from not having `libc-bin` installed. Did you try expressly installing that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are missing `libc-bin` but can't install it.
To install it:

Boot from an ubuntu installation media and open a terminal
Mount your ubuntu root partition: `sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt`
Chroot into your system: `sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash`
Install libc-bin: `sudo apt-get install libc-bin`
Reboot your system and it should work fine

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I should just boot ubuntu from the usb I installed it with?

Comment: Yes Boot from that CD and execute the commands. Dont forget to replace /dev/sdX with the right drive.

Comment: the first command said 'mount: special device /dev/sdX does not exist'

Comment: the second one did 'chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
'

Comment: Are you sure you have mounted the right partition to /mnt? The partition with your root filesystem.

Comment: I am not sure,  how can I check and fix that

Comment: Log into your normal system. There you can list your disks with `lsblk` check which disk is mounted at the mountpoint `/` Mount that disk in the first step of my answer.

Comment: `mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda1 is already mounted on /mnt`

Comment: also the final command came up like this `dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
`

Comment: You ran the commands from the booted  Installation media?

Comment: If that is the case, please check if the following two lines are in the file `/etc/sudoers`: `Defaults        env_reset` and 
`Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`

Comment: If you mean that I booted from a usb and hit try without installing then yes. How can I check those files because I cannot seem to find them.